# django.db.utils.DataError: length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760

Tags: python, django

I was trying to push my code to the heroku and when I migrate my manage.py, it causes this error: django.db.utils.DataError: length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760 .

First, my length has been set to 100000000 and I change it back to 1000 and make migrations. But even after that I still got this Error. I try to search my whole files and everything is set to 1000. Help me to solve the problem!

Comment: Likely you have a migration file that still contains the old length.

Comment: Perhaps using a TextField might make sense instead?

Comment: Did you not have the same error on your development machine? If not, it's likely because you are using a different database in development (e.g. SQLite) vs. production (e.g. PostgreSQL). This is a good example of why it's important to use the same software in development as production: database engines aren't drop-in replacements for each other.

Answer (score 0):

The error takes place when you run the *migration file* that was constructed when you have set it to 100'000'000. You need to look to the migration files and remove the migration file (and the ones that depend on that one, given you made more migration files). You can find these in the `app_name/migations/` directory (with *`app_name`* the name of the module of your app).

Then you can run `makemigrations` again, which will construct a `CharField` with length 1'000, and will update the database accordingly.